# echo file if it exist. if not echo "default.png" php

Tags: php

I have a script that echo's usernames an inserts that into img src. This works great as long as the image is in the directory. How can I create an if statement that only echos the below command if the file exist? If it doesn't exist show default.png

I tried using mod_rewrite and have had zero luck with it..

```
<div class="contactphoto"><img src="contactphoto/<? echo  ($note['user_name'] == "Support")? $note['first_name'].''.$note['last_name'] : $note['user_name'];?>.png"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
<?php 
$file = ($note['user_name'] == "Support") ? $note['first_name'].''.$note['last_name'] : $note['user_name'];
$file .= '.png';

if(!file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} .'/'.$file)){
    $file = 'placeholder.png';
}
?>
<div class="contactphoto">
    <img src="contactphoto/<?php echo $file; ?>"/>
</div>
```

If that fails, try a test ( this should match the path of the image ) also watch out for case sensitivity:

```
echo $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} .'/'.$file;
```

Comment: Eddie.

I had to modify the: $file .= 'png'; to $file .= '.png';

The else statement overwrites all of the other images. Even if the file exists.

Comment: @ipengineer  It may be down to file_exists no accounting for relative paths.. try the edited code above.. ( and oop's your right, I forgot the . ) ( Second Edit.. Tested code and it works )

Comment: same problem.. else overwrites if statement.

Comment: @ipengineer try removing the $file lines and setting it to $file ='yourfilename.png' to test for sure..., also if your running this on a unix machine watch out for the case sensitivity

Comment: I had to add the url to the if(file_exists)

if(file_exists("$url/$file"))

Answer (score 7):

The name says it all: [file_exists()](http://php.net/file_exists)